# Cant find libpq-fe.h when compiling the libpqxx C++ library for postgresql

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

Am trying to install the libpqxx library to use C++ to connect to postgresDB am using Msys and Mingw32. I get this message(below) on the console when I run `./configure` on the msys console. when I check in the `pg_config --includedir` directory I can see the header file libpq-fe.h is there, where am I not doing something right. I am on a windows platform I have installed postgres v.10 the libpqxx version is 4.0 also the path environment I did set it like so export `PATH="$PATH:/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/bin"`

```
checking for pg_config... /c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/bin/pg_config
./configure: line 15928: /c/Program: No such file or directory
configure: using PostgreSQL headers at
./configure: line 15931: /c/Program: No such file or directory
configure: using PostgreSQL libraries at
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking ability to compile programs using the standard C library... yes
checking for library containing select... no
checking for main in -lws2_32... yes
checking /libpq-fe.h usability... no
checking /libpq-fe.h presence... no
checking for /libpq-fe.h... no
configure: error:
Can't find libpq-fe.h in .  Are you sure the libpq
    headers are installed correctly?  They should be in the directory returned by
    "pg_config --includedir".
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem its the spacing in the environment PATH varibale so instead of installing postgres in the Program files folder I created another folder with no white space in its name so my export was something like this `PATH="$PATH:/c/MyPostgreSQLFOLDER/PostgreSQL/10/bin"` you can name the folder whatever you want just dont include any spaces in the name. Hope this helps  anyone out there.